# PHP: Wordpress Test Page

Tags: php, wordpress, server

#### The problem!

I have a `Wordpress`  site up and running. I wanted to add a custom page, for example if I browse to site.com/mytest it would display just `Hello world` without any `css` etc.

#### What I've tried

I added a `mytest.php` file under `var/www/wp-content/` and tried to browse to it. (The code simply echo a static text).

What I got was simply a 404 page by Wordpress.

Comment: You need to create the page in wordpress and then create a custom template for that page. When you edit the page you can see its ID in the URL.. ?post=1&action=edit then its ID would be 1. Then create a file called page-1.php and write Hello World in that.

Comment: You're getting a 404 because that's not how you create pages in WP, as @Bolli kindly said. I gave [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953252/wordpress-template-object-not-found/31954248#31954248) answer a while ago that sheds light on this very problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view the file you uploaded, browse: site.com/wp-content/mytest.php

If you just type site.com/mytest , wordpress will thin you are reffering to a page stored in the wp-database. Since it's not you cant view it.

To add the page in the menu, use custom menu and add as "Custom link".

Comment: Thank you, I was able to browse to my file when I saved it in wp-content and browsed to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your page a wp custom page template by adding this at the top:

```
/*
Template Name:Your Page Name
*/
```

Then create a page in the wordpress dashboard pages and select your page template from the page template dropdown.